# how to break the skip the loop if the value of is categories=""?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

This my script , I want to skip the loop if value of categories="" in the database. How could I do that ??

```
   public function display_international( ) {
                $query = 'SELECT *
      FROM
       tourDB
      WHERE 
        tour_type = "international"';
               $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
                  if ( $result !== false && mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
                       while ( $i = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
                               $international_cats = stripslashes( $i[ 'categories' ] );
                              $international_display .= <<<PANEL_DISPLAY
<a class="international-tour-box-element" href=# >$international_cats</a>
PANEL_DISPLAY;
                        } //$b = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )
                } //$result !== false && mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0
                else {
                         $international_display = <<<PANEL_DISPLAY
<a class="international-tour-box-element" href="#" >No tours !</a>
PANEL_DISPLAY;
                }
                return $international_display;
        }
```

Comment: if ($categories== '' ) {break;}

Comment: You can use either "break" to break the loop, or "continue" to skip the rest of the loop iteration, and continue with the next one. Simply add a if($['categories'] == '') continue; to skip the rest of the current iteration. Alternatively add if($['categories'] == '') break; to terminate the loop all together.

Comment: `if ($categories== '' ) {} else{ rest of your codes }`

Comment: @tomahaug - post it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either "break" to break the loop, or "continue" to skip the rest of the loop iteration, and continue with the next one.

Simply do the following to skip the rest of the current iteration.

```
if($['categories'] == '') continue;
```

Alternatively do the following to terminate the loop all together.

```
if($['categories'] == '') break;
```

Comment: Sidenote: Some developers don't like the use of "continue". So you should consider if using an if-statement would be a better solution (some developers would argue, that it's easier to determine application flow when looking at the code).

Answer (score 0):

This my help you:

```
public function display_international( ) {
                $query = 'SELECT *
      FROM
       tourDB
      WHERE 
        tour_type = "international"';
               $result = mysql_query( $query ) or die( mysql_error() );
                  if ( $result !== false && mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ) {
                       while ( $i = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
                           if (!$i[ 'categories' ]) {
                             continue; // use break; to terminate continue to skip loop
                           }
                               $international_cats = stripslashes( $i[ 'categories' ] );
                              $international_display .= <<<PANEL_DISPLAY
<a class="international-tour-box-element" href=# >$international_cats</a>
PANEL_DISPLAY;
                        } //$b = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )
                } //$result !== false && mysql_num_rows( $result ) > 0
                else {
                         $international_display = <<<PANEL_DISPLAY
<a class="international-tour-box-element" href="#" >No tours !</a>
PANEL_DISPLAY;
                }
                return $international_display;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Exit the loop:

```
if ($i['categories'] == '') {
    break;
}
```

Skip this value in the loop:

```
while ( $i = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) {
    if ($i['categories'] != '') {
        // Rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use break to skip the loop or continue to skip the current iteration.

For example

```
if( $categories == "" ) {
    break; //or continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to the next element in the result

```
if( empty($i[ 'categories' ]) continue;
```

or break it

```
if( empty($i[ 'categories' ]) break;
```